# How to lock mysql before exporting data?

Tags: mysql

How to lock mysql before exporting data?

```
Database == MyISAM
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a transaction in your export. All queries are executed in one go and other queries are not able to 'interrupt' (they are queued).

`START TRANSACTION;`

Now do your export:
`COMMIT;`

Of if something went wrong with one of you export queries:
`ROLLBACK;`

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

**If you have InnoDb and you want to lock the tables:**

Just call `LOCK TABLES table WRITE`

And after exporting: `UNLOCK TABLES`

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: What will happen when a process tries to write to the table while it is locked? Is it going to wait until the lock is released! Or an error would arise?

Comment: LOCK TABLES is just for InnoDB, no for MyISAM :-(

Comment: Oops, that's true. But why don't you export your data in a transaction?

Comment: What? I do not understand :( Examples?

Comment: Without using transactions, it is not?